# Tkinter Text widget tag_add does not work second time

Tags: text, tkinter, tags, addition

I am writing my first python app for the last 20 years. I have a problem with the tag_add() function of the Tkinter Text widget. Adding a tag just works the first time, but not the second time. I checked with tag_names() if my tag got deleted on unchecking the "Highlight Errors" checkbutton. And it is deleted. It is even re-added on checking the checkbutton again, but the text is not colored on second attempt.

Anyone an idea?
As its the first python code for years, do you have feedback to the way I have implemented and structured it? (Sorry cant get away from CamelCase)

Thanks in advance
SLi

```
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH, END, N, W, S, TOP, BOTTOM, INSERT, LEFT, RIGHT, SUNKEN, RAISED, X, Y, PanedWindow, Frame, LabelFrame, Scrollbar, Checkbutton, Entry, Button, Label, Text, Menu, IntVar
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initializeUiVariables()
        self.doWindowSetup()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.doColorSetup()


    def doWindowSetup(self):
        self.parent.title('PACE Client Log Viewer')
        self.screenWidth = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screenHeight = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        desiredWindowWidth = (self.screenWidth * 1.0)
        desiredWindowHeight = (self.screenHeight * 1.0)
        x = (self.screenWidth / 2) - (desiredWindowWidth / 2)
        y = (self.screenHeight / 2) - (desiredWindowHeight / 2)
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (desiredWindowWidth, desiredWindowHeight, x, y))


    def initializeUiVariables(self):
        self.fontSize = 12
        self.highlightErrors = IntVar()



    def createWidgets(self):
        panedWindow = PanedWindow(sashrelief=RAISED)
        panedWindow.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.wText = ScrolledText(panedWindow)
        self.wText.config(font=("consolas", self.fontSize))
        self.wText.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        panedWindow.add(self.wText, minsize=(self.screenWidth * 0.75))
        self.wText.insert(END, "2018-09-28 11:15:03 GMT - my.app.id (ERROR): Class:CertChecker:error: No certificate loaded.  Load certificate before continuing.\n2018-09-28 11:15:07 GMT - my.app.id (INFO): Class:PerformInitialization: begin - version 0.3.10")

        frameToolbar = Frame(panedWindow, padx=10)
        frameToolbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        panedWindow.add(frameToolbar)

        # Highlight Options
        frameHighlightOptions = LabelFrame(frameToolbar, text="Highlight", padx=5, pady=5)
        frameHighlightOptions.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        cbErrors = Checkbutton(frameHighlightOptions, text="Errors", anchor=W, padx=5, justify=LEFT, variable=self.highlightErrors, command=self.onHighlightErrors)
        cbErrors.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    def doColorSetup(self):
        self.wText.tag_config("highlightError", background="#EE2C2C", foreground="#FFFFFF") # red


    def onHighlightErrors(self):
        if self.highlightErrors.get() == 0:
            self.wText.tag_delete("highlightError")
        else:
            self.highlightRow("error", "highlightError")


    def highlightRow(self, pattern, tag):
        self.highlightPattern(pattern, tag, True)


    def highlightPattern(self, pattern, tag, highlightRow=False):
        start = self.wText.index("1.0")
        end = self.wText.index(END)
        self.wText.mark_set("matchStart", start)
        self.wText.mark_set("matchEnd", start)
        self.wText.mark_set("searchLimit", end)

        count = IntVar()
        while True:
            index = self.wText.search(pattern, "matchEnd","searchLimit", count=count, regexp=True, nocase=True)
            if index == "": break
            if count.get() == 0: break # degenerate pattern which matches zero-length strings
            if highlightRow:
                row, col = index.split('.')
                self.wText.mark_set("matchStart", "%s.%s" % (int(row), 0))
            else:
                self.wText.mark_set("matchStart", index)

            if highlightRow:
                lineEndIndex = self.wText.search("\n", index, "searchLimit", count=count, regexp=False, nocase=False)
                row, col = lineEndIndex.split('.')
                self.wText.mark_set("matchEnd", lineEndIndex)
            else:
                self.wText.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.wText.tag_add(tag, "matchStart", "matchEnd")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [mcve]. There appears to be a lot of code unrelated to this question, such as the imports from Cocoa.

Comment: Updated the example and removed unnecessary imports and a bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete the tag, you destroy all of the information associated with that tag. The next time you add the tag it has no colors associate with it, so you can't see the tag.

Instead of deleting the tag, you should just remove it from the text.

Replace this:

```
self.wText.tag_delete("highlightError")
```

... with this:

```
self.wText.tag_remove("highlightError", "1.0", "end")
```

Comment: Very great! Thank you @Bryan Oakley.